# C++ single header library generator

Tags: open-source, software-development, c++, programming

Is there a tool that generates a single header out of a header-only C++ library consisting of `.h` and `.tcc` (headers for template function definitions) files?

It should perform partial pre-processing, for example replace `#include`'s 
of the headers belonging to the same source code tree, but leave `#include`'s of external headers.

For example Catch (unit testing framework) uses a Python script (https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/tree/master/scripts) which seems to be custom written.

Is there a reusable tool for this? For example a CMake plugin, etc.

Comment: You should be able to run the file(s) through the `g++` compiler with the `-E` flag, (you may need to create a stub cpp file that just does the includes), to do a lot of the work for you. You may even discover a flag for don't pre-process system _Most C++ compilers give the option of just pre-processing._

Comment: I don't think you'll find a tool like that. Why would you even need it? Also, 'Catch' doesn't seem to properly parse C++, I'm guessing it's more of a glorified copy-paste mechanism. I also don't find it that significant to avoid having multiple include files.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [Quom](https://github.com/Viatorus/quom):

> Quom is a single header generator for C/C++ libraries.

As input, it expects the main header file, which has to include all your sources (directly or indirectly). In the output, it inlined all local includes (`#include "..."`) but not the system includes (`#include <...>`).

Its README file has an example.